# Trying to join two tables linq to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following tables:

```
Table Name: console_details               Table Name: console_features
-------------------                         -----------------
| console_id      |                         |       id      |
-------------------                         -----------------
|console_name     |                         |     bluray    |
-------------------                         -----------------
|console_type     |                         |   harddrive   |
-------------------                         -----------------
|console_startdate|
-------------------
```

The console_id field and the id field both share the same data common fields I want to join these two tables from my linq to sql query and get the harddrive size for the console. I wasn't able to find another question similar to this on stackoverflow. So any suggestions?

Here is my linq code :

```
public IEnumerable<console_details> GetConsole(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext mydatabase = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var results = from data in mydatabase.console_details
                  where data.console_startdate >= startDate &&
                        endDate >= data.console_startdate
                  select data;

    return results;
}
```

Comment: You say that you have two tables, console_details and console_features. However in your query, you are trying to select data from a third table called game_console. How the latter table is associated with console_details and console_features? I assume that this table, game_console, would have a console_id. So why are you looking for joining console_details and console_features and not join immediately the game_console with console_features? Which are the fileds you want to select at the end? Thanks

Comment: sorry please view the new edit

Comment: no problem at all dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
DataClasses1DataContext mydatabase = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var results = from cd in mydatabase.console_details   
              join cf in mydatabase.console_features
              on cd.console_id equals cf.id
              where cd.console_startdate >= startDate && 
                    endDate >= cd.console_startdate
              select new { Name = cd.console_name, HardDriveSize = cf.harddrive };
```

With the above query you get a sequence of objects of an anonymous type with two properties

- `Name`, which is the console_name.
- `HardDriveSize`, which is the size of the hard drive.

**UPDATE**

At first we have to declare a type that will have all the properties we need. I will call this type `ConsoleView`. You are free to call it whatever you want, but you have to make the corresponding changes in the following code.

```
public class ConsoleView
{
    // console_id
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // console_name
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // console_type
    public string ConsoleType {get; set; }

    // console_startdate
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    // harddrive
    public int HardDrive { get; set; }
}
```

I *assume* that the type of `harddrive` is int and the type of `console_type` is string. 
If that's not true, you have to change them correspondingly.

Then your method should change to the following one:

```
public IEnumerable<ConsoleView> GetConsole(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext mydatabase = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    IEnumerable<ConsoleView> results = from cd in mydatabase.console_details   
                                       join cf in mydatabase.console_features
                                       on cd.console_id equals cf.id
                                       where cd.console_startdate >= startDate && 
                                       endDate >= cd.console_startdate
                                       select new ConsoleView
                                       {
                                           Id = cd.console_id, 
                                           Name = cd.console_name, 
                                           ConsoleType = cd.console_type,
                                           StartDate = cd.console_startdate,
                                           HardDriveSize = cf.harddrive 
                                       };

    return results;
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

As I understand from the error you have posted on your comments, you have an issue with your data context's. So, if DataClasses1DataContext has been built for accessing `console_details` and DataClasses2DataContext  has been built for accessing `console_features`, then you have to change the code in the method to the following one:

```
public IEnumerable<ConsoleView> GetConsole(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext mydatabase1 = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    DataClasses2DataContext mydatabase2 = new DataClasses2DataContext();

    IEnumerable<ConsoleView> results = from cd in mydatabase1.console_details   
                                       join cf in mydatabase2.console_features
                                       on cd.console_id equals cf.id
                                       where cd.console_startdate >= startDate && 
                                       endDate >= cd.console_startdate
                                       select new ConsoleView
                                       {
                                           Id = cd.console_id, 
                                           Name = cd.console_name, 
                                           ConsoleType = cd.console_type,
                                           StartDate = cd.console_startdate,
                                           HardDriveSize = cf.harddrive 
                                       };

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity I am ignoring your startdate and enddate variables in my query.
Because I do not have your data and you did not provide sampledata, I have created a testcase using Linq-to-Objects instead of Linq-to-SQL:

There are 2 classes representing your tables:

```
public class console_details
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string console_name { get; set; }
    public string console_type { get; set; }
}

public class console_features
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double blueray { get; set; }
    public double Harddrive { get; set; }
}
```

The sample data looks like this:

```
var consoleList = new List<console_details>()
{
    new console_details() {Id = 1, console_name = "Ps4", console_type ="Next-Gen"},
    new console_details() {Id = 2, console_name = "XB1", console_type ="Next-Gen"}
};

var featuresList = new List<console_features>()
{
    new console_features() {Id = 1, blueray = 23.9, Harddrive = 100},
    new console_features() {Id = 2, blueray = 30, Harddrive = 150}
};
```

Last but not least I created a ViewModel class to strongly type the result:

```
public class ConsoleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double HardDrive { get; set; }
}
```

With this the query and the output look like this:

```
var joinedResults = from con in consoleList
                    join feat in featuresList on con.Id equals feat.Id
                    select new ConsoleViewModel
                    {
                        Id = con.Id,
                        Name = con.console_name,
                        HardDrive = feat.Harddrive
                    };
```

[image]

Using this, your method should look similar to this:

```
public IEnumerable<ConsoleViewModel> GetConsole(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext mydatabase = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var results = from data in mydatabase.console_details
                  join feat in mydatabase.console features on data.Id equals feat.Id
                  where data.console_startdate >= startDate
                        && endDate >= data.console_startdate
                  select new ConsoleViewModel
                    {
                        Id = con.Id,
                        Name = con.console_name,
                        HardDrive = feat.Harddrive
                    };
    return results;
}
```